# local notification in android starts immediately rather at the given time

Tags: android, time, notifications

```
    long when = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
    when += 10000;

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            getApplicationContext())
            .setWhen(when)
            .setContentText(notificationContent)
            .setContentTitle(notificationTitle)
            .setSmallIcon(smalIcon)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setTicker(notificationTitle) 
            .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS| Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE| Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

This runs in the onCreate, however, my notification gets created instantly when the app starts, rather then after 10 seconds.
Whats wrong ?

Even

```
.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis()+10000)
```

does not make it show after 10 seconds. it shows directly.

Answer (score 6):

From the documentation for `setWhen(...)`...

> Add a timestamp pertaining to the notification (usually the time the event occurred). It will be shown in the notification content view by default; use setShowWhen to control this.

The `setWhen(...)` method doesn't set a time (delay) for when a `Notification` should be displayed. It's used to show the time that some event has occured.

For example, suppose your app monitors receiving SMS messages - when a message arrives you would create a `Notification` saying "You have a new SMS message" and you'd use `setWhen(...)` to show the time that the message was received.

If you want to set a particular delay or fixed time for an event to occur and an associated  `Notification` to be shown, use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).